# Are Effect Events really necessary?

Tags: reactjs

In the following official example, I use plain JS functions instead of Effect Events, isn't this more concise?

Are Effect Events really necessary?

```
// official example

function ChatRoom({ roomId, theme }) {
  const onConnected = useEffectEvent(() => {
    showNotification('Connected!', theme);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const connection = createConnection(serverUrl, roomId);
    connection.on('connected', () => {
      onConnected();
    });
    connection.connect();
    return () => connection.disconnect();
  }, [roomId]);

  return <h1>Welcome to the {roomId} room!</h1>
}

// My change 
function ChatRoom({ roomId, theme }) {
  function play() {
    showNotification('Connected!', theme);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const connection = createConnection(serverUrl, roomId);
    connection.on('connected', () => {
      play();
    });
    connection.connect();
    return () => connection.disconnect();
  }, [roomId]);

  return <h1>Welcome to the {roomId} room!</h1>
}
```

This is the official example of Event Effect:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bd0s8d?file=/App.js&utm_medium=sandpack
This is my change:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-chaum-cwnyr9

Answer (score 1):

Your change is incorrect, because your function `play` is missing in the dependency array of the `useEffect`, and [every reactive value read by an Effect must be declared as its dependency](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects#react-verifies-that-you-specified-every-reactive-value-as-a-dependency).

To make it correct, you would need to add `play` in the dependencies of the `useEffect`, and wrap it in a `useCallback` with `theme` as dependency. But then it's exactly the same as if you didn't extract `showNotification` and put `theme` in the dependencies of the `useEffect` directly.

This is the purpose of [`useEffectEvent`](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_useEffectEvent): to extract non-reactive logic out of effects, without the need to put it in the dependencies, as explained [in the docs](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#extracting-non-reactive-logic-out-of-effects).

Please note that it is currently an **experimental** feature.